# LibGdx Dynamic (Runtime) Textures

Tags: android, libgdx

I am drawing some dots to represent players of two teams on a map.
Each team has its own colour.
Important to note that the dot contains two circles, outer border and a inner fill so there will be two colours, with the border always being the same.

It makes sense for me to generate this at runtime rather than packing a texture for each combination.

Upon research, there seems to many ways to achieve this but each has a associated problem

**ShapeRenderer**

ShapeRenderer is for debugging purposes and should not be used for usual drawing as stated by a LibGdx developer here
http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8573&p=38930
For this reason I avoided using this

**Pixmap**

This was very promising, I liked the idea that I could just generate two textures and re-use them for each sprite. The biggest problem with this is that Textures made via Pixmap are un-managed so if the OpenGL context is lost and regained (This can be easily reproduced in an Android application, if the user backgrounds the app and restores it from foreground). I am primarily targetting Android so this an issue for me

**Texture Re-Colour**

Was thinking I could create a grey scale dot and re-colour it but since my asset has two parts to it, I am not sure how I could selectively choose the inner circle and fill it.

**Question 1 How Do I Restore Pixmap Texture On Context Loss?**

I have not found an example which details how to do this? I assume it is going to be done in the `resume` lifecycle callback but what do I need to do?

**Question 2 Alternative Way?**

Is there an alternative way for my issue perhaps?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: ShapeRenderer is perfectly suitable for runtime gameplay. There are cases where it might be slower than drawing a sprite, such as when drawing a large filled circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load just one texture with white circle. Use `SpriteBatch` to draw players: first call `batch.setColor(borderColor)` and draw the circle `Texture` with outer radius, then call `batch.setColor(fillColor)` and draw it with inner radius. Sure there is a some performance impact because of drawing fill part twice, but if circles are small enough the impact is going to be negligible.